# Java Multithreading - skipping lines of code?

Tags: java

I've been working on a program where you can play Pong on it and I'm relatively new to multithreading. When I run this block of code, it's supposed to display a little box in the top left corner where a ball in bouncing in a box and a big rectangle in the center. The ball comes, but the rectangle doesn't.

```
private void gameRender() {

    if( dbImage == null ) {
        dbImage = createImage( dbWIDTH, dbHEIGHT );
        if( dbImage == null ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "dbImage is null", "Error",                   JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            return;
        }
        else
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    }

    dbg.setColor( Color.white );
    dbg.fillRect( 100, 150, dbWIDTH, dbHEIGHT );
    dbg.setColor( Color.blue );
    dbg.drawRect( 110, 110, 10, 5 );
    g = getGraphics();
    ball = new PongBall( g );
    ball.run();
    if( gameOver )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "GAME OVER", "GAME OVER", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
}
```

Here's the PongBall thread

```
class PongBall extends Thread {

private boolean keepGoing;
private Graphics g;
private int x = 7, xChange = 7;
private int y = 0, yChange = 2;
private int diameter = 10;
private int rectLeftX = 0, rectRightX = 100;
private int rectTopY = 0, rectBottomY = 100;

public PongBall( Graphics graphics ) {
    g = graphics;
    keepGoing = true;
}

public void pleaseStop() { keepGoing = false; }

public void run() {


    g.drawRect( rectLeftX, rectTopY, rectRightX - rectLeftX, rectBottomY - rectTopY );

    while( keepGoing ) {

        g.setColor( Color.white );
        g.fillOval( x, y, diameter, diameter );

        if( x + xChange <= rectLeftX )
            xChange = -xChange;
        if( x + xChange >= rectRightX )
            xChange = -xChange;

        if( y + yChange <= rectTopY )
            yChange = -yChange;
        if( y + yChange >= rectBottomY )
            yChange = -yChange;

        x = x + xChange;
        y = y + yChange;

        g.setColor( Color.red );
        g.fillOval( x, y, diameter, diameter );

        try {
            Thread.sleep( 50 );
        }
        catch( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.err.println( "sleep exception" );
        }
    }
}
```

}
As you can probably see, "dbg.fillRect( 100, 150, dbWIDTH, dbHEIGHT );" is skipped and ball.run() just runs. Is there something I'm not doing and how can I fix this?

Also, I'm new the stackoverflow.com, so if I gave too much or too little code, or anything went wrong, I apologize.

Comment: This doesn't actually appear to involve multiple threads, since you're just calling `run()` on your `PongBall`, rather than calling `start()`. (Note that's probably a good thing, since updating the UI should occur on a single thread.) I think your problem is that you're just creating an image, but not actually rendering it to the screen.

Comment: I do render it to the screen. I eliminated the "ball.run()" line of code while I tested it and the rectangle showed up, but with that line of code it doesn't. But thank you for the tip that one thread should update the UI

Comment: Its hard to tell, but I think your ball is being drawn over the rectangle and erasing it.  Use a debugger to see what is happening, because right now you only have one thread, anyway.

Comment: Is this a full-screen GUI? You really shouldn't be getting the Graphics object of a component by calling `getGraphics()` on the component but rather painting should be done in the JComponent's `paintComponent(...)` method using the Graphics object given you by the JVM (note that it's perfectly fine to get a BufferedImage's Graphics object via `getGraphics()` as long as you dispose of it properly).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do all your drawing in the Swing thread.  You can achieve this by using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) in your PongBall thread to include all the code which updates the GUI.

This avoid any multi-threaded problems in the GUI, because only one thread is used to update the display.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have made two mistakes.
Firstly, you should call method "start()" to start a thread instead of "run()".
secondly, how to archive the object of Graphics of Swing Component ? don't use the method "getGraphics()", it doesn't work. you should override method paintComponent(Graphics g).

Comment: apologize for the second point of my answer, it works well because you make a thread to loop to draw.